# javascript prototype function - 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, this

Problem:
I have a piece of code that throws an error: `this.isEmpty is not a function`,
and I cannot figure out why. Following is the fragment [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/m9L96vxo/6/):

```
function addAlbumGrid(){
  const MainGrid = new AlbumGrid ()
return MainGrid
}

function AlbumGrid() {
  MainGrid.call(this)
}

var parentPrototype = Object.create(AlbumGrid.prototype)
parentPrototype.constructor = MainGrid
MainGrid.prototype = parentPrototype

AlbumGrid.prototype.addPhotoBox = function () {

  MainGrid.prototype.add.call(this)
}

function MainGrid(){
}

MainGrid.prototype = {
  isEmpty: function() {
    {
      return false
    }
  },

  add:function() {
    if(!this.isEmpty())
    {
      return false
    }
  }
}

var AlbumGrid=addAlbumGrid()
AlbumGrid.addPhotoBox()
```

Following is code that works [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/6z11gy3u/):

```
function animal()  {
}
animal.prototype = {
  canWalk: function () {
    return true
  },
  move: function () {
  if(this.canWalk()) {alert ('moving')}
 }
}
function bird() {
  animal.call(this)
}
var animalProto = Object.create(animal.prototype)
animalProto.constructor = bird
bird.prototype = animalProto

bird.prototype.fly = function () {
  animal.prototype.move.call(this)
}

let fluffy = new bird ()
fluffy.fly()
```

Searching for help I landed at [this page](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3), can it be that I am somewhere loosing the context of `this`, and it is pointing to something I don't want?

In that case, would a solution using composition be an option (object.assign(..))?

Or can it be anything else?

I hope somebody can shed a light.

Thank you...

*Ps edit: I have now updated the code, the first 3 comments reflected an older version of this post.*

Comment: Not sure why you want to avoid `this`, but your code never uses `self`, so how can we know where the problem is? Without having a more detailed objective *(other than 'get rid of `this`')*, how can we answer?

Comment: I agree with @squint. Why would you avoid this? It's a normal language construct.

Comment: i understand. i will try to reproduce the problem with code that i can paste here, and then update the question. I just thought that the context might be a problem, so jumped to asking about alternative solutions..

Comment: If the code you've posted here works but your real code does not, then we cannot help you with it. You'll need to post your actual code that causes the error.

Comment: hi, I have now updated the question with the code that is failing.

Comment: Not sure why you're assigning an object to `MainGrid.prototype` *twice*, but the issue is here... `MainGrid.prototype.add.call(this)` With this call, the value of `this` in the `add` method will be the `AlbumGrid` instance that you created, which only has a `addPhotoBox()` method. `MainGrid` inherits from `AlbumGrid` *(at least it did for a moment until you overwrote the `.prototype` again)*, not the other way around.

Comment: @squint; THANK YOU :)

Comment: @squint; was typing too slow :)  The inverted inheritance comes from this being actually a function where parent and descendant had been mistakenly swapped in the argument, i was too sleepy and didnt notice :)  Albumgrid is what I want to use here, inheriting from MainGrid. This also solves the 'double prototyping' issue.  There is also a TetrisGrid that inherits from MainGrid but adds gaming logic and you can place the boxes in shapes. And  a FamTreeGrid that has database logic.  Hence my question about composition (Shapemanipulator, dbInteractor, etc?)

Comment: Sleepy coding... I know what you mean!